# Application not showing up in Google Play searches for 3.x devices

Tags: android

I realized that my application doesn't show up in searches on Google Play if I search for it using a Samsung 10" with Android 3.x.

If I install it (by using adb or maven android plugin) everything works as expected (core functionalities, compatibility mode, ...).

I studied all guides concerning targeting different devices, screens, tried different combinations in Manifest metadata and actually configuration looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
          android:maxSdkVersion="13" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

And in the maven android plugin configuration I specified:

```
<platform>10</platform>
```

In the Google Play developers console the apk is correctly reported for:

```
API Level: 7-13
Supported screens: small-xlarge
```

What's wrong with my metadata?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other tags also affect the visibility of your app to the Android Market. I remember one time that an app I was working on is not showing up in the market as well. I realized that my application is using TELEPHONY services, however my device, a MOTOROLA Xoom doesn't have TELEPHONY services available which in turn filters the app in the Android Market. I set the an attribute in TELEPHONY services to not required (still in the AndroidManifest, I forgot the specific tag) and fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, you pointed me in the right direction! It was one of the permissions in the manifest

Comment: Can you tell me what was your problem? I have a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068458/my-free-version-app-is-not-showing-in-google-play-but-paid-version-is