# My free version app is not showing in google play, but paid version is

Tags: google-play

After read lots of other posts and could not find an answer, I ask if someone had the same problem.

I wrote two versions of the same APP: one for free and another paid version.

Hours after publish both, only the paid version can be found in google play. The free version does not "exists" if I use the search tool (using web or devices), but it is PUBLISHED in developer console.

The most weird is the fact I also can't find the application clicking "More From Developer"! Where the free version is?!

Comparing the Manifest of both, they are the same except the package and name.

Any one can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: there is a bug in the new layout of developer console. I added two languages in my application: English, Portuguese. But instead of create two different languages, developer console added English twice. With the old interface I removed the second language and create a new Portuguese translation again. It worked!